# Не рабоатет upload для файлов с расширением php, js, css

Tags: php, yii2

Всем привет!
Делаю аплоад файлов(точнее сделал), практически все работает кроме аплоада файлов с раширением php, css, либо с каким-то левым например file.xyz. Пишет ошибку "Разрешена загрузка файлов только со следующими расширениями: eot, ttf, gif, jpg, jpeg, png, css, php, xyz", причем возникает она после валидации на сервере, на фронтенде в форме все нормально.
 
В rules все прписанно правильно т.к. нужные мне изображения и аудиофайлы  успешно прохродят валидацию и загружаются на сервер.

Что может быть? Может какие-та ограничение включены по умолчанию в yii2?
Полазил по докам yii, никаких методов, свойств и флагов связаных с этим не нешел

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте в валидацию вот эти два пункта добавить:

1. `'maxSize' => 1024 * 1024`, (указать нужный размер)
2. `'checkExtensionByMimeType'=>false`